# What are typical ASP.NET MVC - Controller Action Name conventions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, action

I'm struggling to choose appropriate names for my actions. I want to distinguish between actions that return a view to:

1. Create
2. Edit
3. Edit-Create

Here is what I have so far:

```
Create --> Show the Empty Form for Create  
Add    --> Receives data from Create and Save New Entity  
Edit   --> Shows Existing Entity in a form for editing  
Update --> Saves the changes on an existing Entity  
???    --> Shows the form for either editing or creating depending on the 
           situation  
Save   --> Either saves or updates the entity depending on whether the entity 
           already exists or not.
```

So, What would be an appropriate name for the action that Shows the `Create/Edit` view, which sends its data to `Save`.

I had considered `CreateEdit` since it's clear and specific, but I'm not sure. Any suggestions?

Comment: Create is usually both the form-shower (GET) and the data-receiver (POST).

Comment: I've seen the these combined in overloads, and wondered if anyone had any pros or cons for this approach.

Comment: @bzarah Cons? Don't know any. Pros? Makes you adhere to REST standards.

Comment: I guess the reason I don't like overloading these methods is that I would never do this normally in code. If I had two methods that did something VERY different like show an empty form vs save something to a database, I'd give them different names, not overload them. I've done enough reading on REST to understand the basics, but really can't see any reason why it's important for my intranet web application.

Comment: Have a look at REST. They're both doing a create, one with a GET and the other with a POST verb. Together, the method and verb specify what's going on. They're both concerned with create - one with showing the create form and the other with processing input from it. *Internally* they may do something different, but conceptually they're linked.

Comment: Thanks for the comments Mike. I'm going to go with your suggestion below, mainly since it seems to follow accepted standards. I will do more research on REST. It seems I keep coming back to it as a topic, but still don't see what the fuss is about when building web applications for browsers. Hopefully I will see the light :)

Comment: @bzarah I read you regarding overloading. Problem is, if you give them different names, you make the API exposed to your web users inconsistent and less RESTful. (I think there are some other drawbacks as well since ASP.NET MVC relies on convention over configuration, letting you use defaults in some places if you go with the GET/POST-same-name program.) You could technically expose the same URL for two action methods with different names, but that sounds like a maintainability nightmare.

Comment: If the goal is a clean API, why not just name the method that shows the Edit "ShowEdit" and the method that saves the entity "Save". Would that not be a cleaner API than using a common name and then decoding a part of the transport (GET vs POST)? Why not just make the method name describe what the method does like you would in any layer of your application? 

It's the next day, and I'm still doing reading on REST. I still haven't seen the light, but with so much support from the community, I'm obviously missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I typically use `Create()` for adding a new entity and `Edit()` for editing one.

I overload the GET & POST methods and add an `[HttpPost]` attribute to the one that receives the data, e.g.:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    // this one renders the input form
    ...
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create( MyViewModel model )
{
    // this one accepts the form post
    if ( ModelState.IsValid )
    {
       ...
       return RedirectToAction( ... );
    }
    return View( model );
}
```

This convention makes it easy to find related methods.

Comment: So, Create (New Entity), Edit (Alter Existing), Create/Edit --> ???
Also, whate are the pros and cons to combining these actions into an overload?

Comment: Create/Edit works fine if you can pass an empty model to the GET method and can detect that the entity is new in the POST method, e.g. by checking for a zero ID. However, my controller methods are so small and are functionally different - i.e. the create method just maps the view model object to a new entity and saves it, whereas the edit method loads the entity and just maps the model on to it - there's no need to save the update if you're using a change-tracking ORM such as NHibernate.

Comment: We're using NHibernate here as well, so saving a new entity and updating an existing one can be done seamlessly from the same method. I'd love to get your thoughts on the pros and cons of overloading the methods for the "Show" and "Persist" actions. I feel like separate action names for each would result in a clearer API. 
That being said, ASP.NET MVC has built in extensibility through ActionMethodSelectorAttributes, and @bzlm has made the point that this is more RESTFful.

Comment: How seamlessly? When you load your entity from a session, there's no need to update it - it's automatic. My session management is handled for me in the global.asax.cs so I don't even think about explicitly updating entities. I use persistence by reachability for new entities - see [Don't Create Aggregate Roots](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/06/29/dont-create-aggregate-roots/) by Udi Dahan. Don't know what you mean by show and persist actions. Do you mean detail and create/edit?

Comment: No need to get into an NHibernate discussion here. The "Show" is the showing of the form for editing and the persist, well, that's the the action that validates and persists  the data sent to the server.

Comment: The Show action method would normally show some details of an entity for viewing only - thus a GET. Persistence would be by Create or Edit with a POST. REST would require that Create is a PUT and Edit is a POST but since browsers don't support PUT, POST is used.